# Space in number format

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

How do I add space as a decimal number separator? The current format is `23456.00` but it has to be `23 456`

I got it to remove the `.00` with `toFixed` already but no luck with the space separator.

```
{{parseFloat(post.meta.price).toFixed(0)}}
```

Perhaps I can change the locale format in the code to fr-FR because that will add the space?

Answer (score 12):

> Perhaps I can change the locale format in the code to fr-FR because that will add the space?

Yes, you can!

```js
price = 23456.00
disp = new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(price)
console.log(disp)
```

reference: [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Answer (score 7):

You can use below function to add a space as a decimal number separator.

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1 ');
}

console.log(formatNumber(2665));
console.log(formatNumber(102665)); 
console.log(formatNumber(111102665));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `toLocaleString` and replace commas with spaces:

```js
const num = 23456.00;
const res = num.toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, " ");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This only works if the thousand separator is a comma - not the case for some locales